# rbuic on windows

Tags: ruby, user-interface, qt

I've had no luck getting the rbuic UI compiler (from qt4-qtruby-1.4.10 release) to produce any output on windows.  Even running rbuic -h does not work.  I'm guessing the output is going somewhere other than stdout... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed my qt environment according to [this](http://tom.paschenda.org/blog/?p=38) and use rbuic according to [this](http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/RubyGUIProject/). 
I have to type rbuic4 so for example:

```
rbuic4 -h
```

outputs the help. 
rbuic outputs default to stdout, so if you want to redirect the output to a file:

```
rbuic4 sampledialog.ui -o sampledialog_ui.rb
```

Does the job. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Same here.  And yes, the exact command line is rbuic4, not rbuic; i should have been more precise.

Comment: Stumbling upon this thread after a while, used the same sources. Turns out that rbuic4 and rbrcc were copied by Qt4 for Windows to %Windows%\SysWOW64, copied them to my Ruby's bin as well. Thanks for the fine answer!